# Code shown as text output

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm a newbie to Facebook app development. It almost works when the page `liked.php` is shown (it's shown when a user liked the site), the PHP code is displayed as text output.

my `liked.php` code: 
deleted for privacy reasons
    ?>

Here's the output(it's shown as blank text):

I simply don't know why. Even the `error_reporting(E_ALL)`; doesn't show anything. Simply blank text output. I use the newest facebook php sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is not in the code but in the configuration of your server. You need to tell the server to execute the php code instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either don't have PHP installed or you're not using a file extension which invokes the PHP engine - is your file called `[Blah].php`?

Some things to check:

- You're serving the file from a web server (not locally)
- The server has PHP installed
- Your webserver is configured to use the PHP engine to handle the file type you're using (usually .php or .php4 or similar)
- creating a new file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`  and serving it should give you lots of info about your PHP install.
- If you have access to the server, you should be able to run PHP from the command line/shell

Comment: I host the app on heroku, which is a partner of facebook in app hosting. And it shows that it is PHP. Nah. I'm gonna contact the support or something like this.